The prime 2 in quadratic number fields
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, for $d$ a squarefree integer.
I have shown that $d \equiv 1 \mod 8$ implies that 2 is totally split and $d \equiv 5 \mod 8$ implies that 2 is inert.
However I am struggling to show the converse, how can I approach this?

By using the Legendre symbol. See, for example, this post.

That only works for $p \neq 2$ ?

There is also a version for $p=2$, see Remark $6.2.8$ here.
